# Generating a Table with two fixed variable and varying the third variable

Tags: list-manipulation, mapthread

I want to generate a table in which two of the variables (x,y) are fixed with 1<->1 correspondence while the third variable is varying in the given range for each each sublist. I want to program for this in the input, NOT by generating the general output and then removing the unnecessary part. Example is given here:

```
fnn[x_, y_, z_] := x*Sin[y]*Cos[z]
xr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
yr = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
zr = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
```

I want the output in the form,

```
{{fnn[1, 6, z]},{fnn[2, 7, z]},{fnn[3, 8, z]},{fnn[4, 9, z]},{fnn[5, 10, z]}},
```

where z varies in the range, `{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}`. I do not need e.g. `fnn[1, 7, z], fnn[2, 8, z]` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

fnn[x_, y_, z_] := x*Sin[y]*Cos[z]
xr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
yr = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
zr = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15};

MapThread[
 Thread[Inactive[fnn][#1, #2, zr]] &,
 {xr, yr}
 ]
```

---

or

```
Inner[Thread[Inactive[fnn][#1, #2, zr]] &, xr, yr, List]
```

---

*Result*

[image]

Comment: Why are the fnn[x,y,z] not evaluated? The output should be like 1*Sin[6]*Cos[11],....... etc?

Comment: I got it. Coz you have added "Inactive" before "fnn". Thanks!

Comment: If these evaluate, then the larger picture would be lost. You can always remove the `Inactive` when you  are satisfied with the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the second and third arguments of `Thread` combined with `MapThread` as follows:

```
Map[Thread] @ Thread[FOO[xr, yr, zr], List, 2]
```

[image]

```
Map[Thread] @ Thread[FOO[xr, yr, zr], List, 2] /. FOO -> fnn
```

[image]

Alternatively, use

```
ReleaseHold @ Map[Thread] @ Thread[Hold[fnn][xr, yr, zr], List, 2]
```

to get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Since all components of `fnn` (`Times`, `Sin`, `Cos`) are [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html), you can simply map
`fnn[xr, yr, #] &` on `zr`:

```
Map[fnn[xr, yr, #] &] @ zr
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f]
Table[f[xr[[n]], yr[[n]], j], {n, Length[xr]}, {j, zr}]
```

> {{f[1, 6, 11], f[1, 6, 12], f[1, 6, 13], f[1, 6, 14],
> f[1, 6, 15]}, {f[2, 7, 11], f[2, 7, 12], f[2, 7, 13], f[2, 7, 14],
> f[2, 7, 15]}, {f[3, 8, 11], f[3, 8, 12], f[3, 8, 13], f[3, 8, 14],
> f[3, 8, 15]}, {f[4, 9, 11], f[4, 9, 12], f[4, 9, 13], f[4, 9, 14],
> f[4, 9, 15]}, {f[5, 10, 11], f[5, 10, 12], f[5, 10, 13],
> f[5, 10, 14], f[5, 10, 15]}}

```
%/.f->fnn
```

> {{Cos[11] Sin[6], Cos[12] Sin[6], Cos[13] Sin[6], Cos[14] Sin[6],
> Cos[15] Sin[6]}, {2 Cos[11] Sin[7], 2 Cos[12] Sin[7],
> 2 Cos[13] Sin[7], 2 Cos[14] Sin[7],
> 2 Cos[15] Sin[7]}, {3 Cos[11] Sin[8], 3 Cos[12] Sin[8],
> 3 Cos[13] Sin[8], 3 Cos[14] Sin[8],
> 3 Cos[15] Sin[8]}, {4 Cos[11] Sin[9], 4 Cos[12] Sin[9],
> 4 Cos[13] Sin[9], 4 Cos[14] Sin[9],
> 4 Cos[15] Sin[9]}, {5 Cos[11] Sin[10], 5 Cos[12] Sin[10],
> 5 Cos[13] Sin[10], 5 Cos[14] Sin[10], 5 Cos[15] Sin[10]}}